# Batch script commands

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to open a cmd window, accept 2 string inputs, change to a local directory, and then execute another batch command with the 2 inputs from within the directory.  I've been googling all afternoon with no real luck. Here is what I have now, it will take the 2 inputs, but it doesn't like the path when executed

```
@echo
set /p fileIn=Name of resource system
set /p actionIn=(add) or (remove)
cd "C:\jboss-eap-7.1.0\jboss-eap-7.1\bin" 
cmd.exe jboss-cli.bat --connect --file="C:\SVN\MCA_2018.05.0_Development_Jboss\Docs\%regionIn%-resources-local-%actionIn%.batch"
```

Comment: `%regionin%` is not defined. And you can just use the `CALL ` command instead of `cmd.exe`. You never use the `%filein%` variable.

Comment: Also, you probably need to use `cd /d "C:\jboss-eap-7.1.0\jboss-eap-7.1\bin"` if your current directory is not `C:`.

Comment: `@echo
set /p regionIn=Name of resource system
echo %regionIn%
set /p actionIn=(add) or (remove)
cd /d "C:\jboss-eap-7.1.0\jboss-eap-7.1\bin" 
call jboss-cli.bat --connect --file="C:\SVN\MCA_2018.05.0_Development_Jboss\Docs\%regionIn%-resources-local-%actionIn%.batch"
pause`

Comment: got this to work based on your suggestions!  Thanks